# mysqlbackup: ERROR: Found extraneous commands at the end

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I'm tring to take backup of  database using MysqlEnterpriseBackup tool (Mysqlbackup) command using below command:

`mysqlbackup  --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --user=Username -p --port=3306  --socket=/path/mysql.sock   --with-timestamp --databases=dbname --datadir=/path/mysql   --backup-dir= /backup path/foldername  backup-and-apply-log`

---

Below error I can see :

> MySQL Enterprise Backup version 4.0.0
>   Linux-3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64-x86_64 [2015/10/17] Copyright (c)
>   2003, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
>
> mysqlbackup: INFO: Starting with following command line ...
>
> mysqlbackup  --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --user=Username -p
>   --port=3306  --socket=/path/mysql.sock   --with-timestamp --databases=dbname --datadir=/path/mysql   --backup-dir= /backup path/foldername  backup-and-apply-log
>
> mysqlbackup: ERROR: Found extraneous commands at the end. Use --help
>   option for usage description.

mysqlbackup failed with errors!

Can you please help me to resolve the above error?

Comment: Why do you specify both port and socket? Have you checked documentation on what parameters can be applied and how?

Comment: The command seems as if you copy-pasted it out from a documentation with default values in the example

Comment: Port & socket I'm used in query because I have 2 more instances on my server, this 2 are must to differentiate it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space after "backup_dir=" and before the backup path as shown in the output above that would cause this error.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that the last argument of the command must be:
backup-to-image, backup or backup-and-apply-log

Comment: They *are* using `backup-and-apply-log`, so this doesn't appear to provide a solution to the question.